# Как получить номер текущей версии приложения из Google Play Market?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Есть необходимость: при очередном запуске приложения определять - появилась ли новая версия приложения в маркете?

Как программно можно определить номер версии приложения из Google Play Маркета?

Текущую версию определяю так:

```
int currrentVersionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.packagename",0).versionCode;
```

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с этим.

Comment: [Несколько разных решений на СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298106/how-to-allow-users-to-check-for-the-latest-app-version-from-inside-the-app).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Старый способ - распарсить страницу:

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    String newVersion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "package name" + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newVersion;

}
```

Bызов:

```
VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker();
String latestVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
```

---

Новый способ - использовать [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/):

1. Создать Firebase проект.
2. Скачать **google_play_service.json** и добавить в свой проект.
3. Создать ключ, к примеру, `android_latest_version_code`
4. В коде:

   ```
   public void initializeFirebase() {
           if (FirebaseApp.getApps(mContext).isEmpty()) {
               FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mContext, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(mContext));
           }
           final FirebaseRemoteConfig config = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
           FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                                                                 .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                                                 .build();
           config.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
   }
   ```

   И сама проверка:

   ```
   int playStoreVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("android_latest_version_code"));
   PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
   int currentAppVersionCode = pInfo.versionCode;

   if(playStoreVersionCode > currentAppVersionCode){
       // показывать окно, что есть новое обновление
   }
   ```
5. Единственный минус - ключ `android_latest_version_code` в Firebase вам нужно будет ручками каждый раз обновлять.

---

Ещё, как вариант - где-то у себя это хранить. К примеру, мы в своих играх такие вещи храним в json файле на сервере. Игра при старте получает этот json (где помимо актуальной версии ещё и куча других нужных нам вещей есть).

Comment: Добавить:
dependencies {
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'}

Comment: @ЛЕО ну, зависимости - это само собой разумеющееся)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> добавить в манифест. Только в одном результате показало: "Depends on the device" вместо номера версии.

Comment: Почему то у меня ругается на int playStoreVersionCode = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString("android_latest_version_code");  Пишет что Incompatible types.(((

Comment: @Романыч поправил ответ.

Comment: @Suvitruf Будет ли ошибкой получать текущую версию = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;?

Comment: @Романыч в случае со сборкой с помощью градла можно и так получать, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 3):

Пардон, но мб проще подцепить облачный ресурс - тот же firebase. При запуске читаете некоторую константу из firebase. Ключи менять каждый раз не нужно. Обновил версию в playmarket - написал новую строку в firebase.

Comment: "Ключи менять каждый раз не нужно", "Обновил версию в playmarket - написал новую строку в firebase" эээм?

Comment: вы предлагаете парсить страницу и каждый раз обновлять ключ? Что это за костыли?