# Как программно узнать текущую версию приложения из Google Play Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Как программно узнать текущую версию приложения из Google Play Market? Может есть какая то библиотека?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/881230/281715

Answer (score 1):

Есть API для консоли разработчика, но точно не стоит его дёргать из клиентского приложения, т.к. вам придётся в него вшивать данные для доступа. Других способов получения версии нет. Да и про API надо ещё смотреть есть ли там такая возможность.

Так что вам остаются 2 варианта:

1. Правильный, сложный и долгий. Сделайте себе сервер, который будет получать номер текущей версии через API консоли разработчика (если там есть такая возможность) или просто парсите HTML страницы приложения в маркете.
2. Парсите HTML страницы приложения в маркете с девайса.

Comment: №1 самый профессионально верный. Все остальное - только для прототипов, иначе костыли.